# Does Using Inherited Widget will rebuild it's Child without using SetState

Tags: flutter, dart

```
class InheritedRepo extends InheritedWidget {
  InheritedRepo({
    super.key,
    required super.child,
    required this.name,

  });
  String name 
  ;
  shouldDoSome() {}

  static InheritedRepo of(BuildContext context) =>
      context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<InheritedRepo>()!;

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(covariant InheritedRepo oldWidget) {
    print("name:$name");
    print("oldWidget.name:${oldWidget.name}");

 
    return true;
  }
}
```

```
  ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () {
       Navigator.of(context).push(
       MaterialPageRoute(
       builder: (context) =>
        InheritedRepo(
        name: 'some name',
        child: const FilePickerScreen()),
         ),
       );
      },
       child: const Text("Filepicker Screen"),
     ),
```

i created a inherited widget but when i tried to modify the value of name variable the child is not rebuilding , even the updateShouldNotify is not invoking , the print statement didn't executed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think **InheritedWidget** will automatically trigger a rebuild of its child widgets when its properties change, the **InheritedWidget** is a otherway of sharing a state to other descendants widgets, it has not function to rebuild the widget. and also for the updateShouldNotify method is used to determine if the widget's descendants should be notified about the change. but, it doesn't directly trigger a rebuild. So, you need to add **setState** to redraw the widget and rebuild the UI. hHere some documentation might help : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html